# Which version of Chrome supports ORTC?

Tags: webrtc, ortc

I heard Google is having plans to support ORTC standards from version 38 or 39, but haven't seen any confirmation on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would seem to require a link to an external resource, and is about speculative browser features rather than 'a programming question.'

Comment: [here you go](http://blog.webrtc.is/2014/07/01/google-chrome-38-39-to-ship-with-ortc-webrtc-1-1-apis/)

Answer (score 1):

https://bloggeek.me/google-roadmap-webrtc/
This was on the roadmap but did not happen.

Programmatically , you can check for the existence of the RTCRtpSender object. It's not there in the canary version (43 as of today) of chrome even.